# Encrypting Strings runs much slower in Spring Boot than on Wildfly26

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, encryption, wildfly

I have a java web service using jakarta and javax.ws.rs. The service takes a GET request and returns a generated captcha image alongside a token containing the encrypted solution. I am using the Cipherhandler class to encrypt the solution string after generating the image from it.

The code in question:

```
@ApplicationPath("/captcha")
@Path("/demo")
@Log4j2
public class Api extends Application {

    private final SecureTextCaptchaHandler handler = new SecureTextCaptchaHandler();
    private final SimpleTextImageRenderer renderer = new SimpleTextImageRenderer();
    private final CaptchaTextGenerator gen = new SimpleCaptchaTextGenerator();
    private final CipherHandler ch = new CipherHandler();
    private final Validator validator = new Validator();

    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTextCaptcha() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String solution = gen.generate(4);
        Captcha captcha = handler.toCaptcha(solution, ch, "SomeSaltSource", "myPassword", renderer, 200, 600, true);
        System.out.println("Serving TextCaptcha took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds.");
        return Response.ok().entity(captcha).build();
    }
```

I have also created a spring boot application with spring boot 3.0.5 that implements the same functionality and runs the exact same code. Essentially it just calls the same methods with the same arguments from a RestController. However I observed that while the image generation takes roughly the same time between the two, encrypting the string to create the token is considerably slower with spring boot.

The spring boot version:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RestController
public class Api {

    private final SecureTextCaptchaHandler handler = new SecureTextCaptchaHandler();
    private final SimpleTextImageRenderer renderer = new SimpleTextImageRenderer();
    private final CaptchaTextGenerator gen = new SimpleCaptchaTextGenerator();
    private final CipherHandler ch = new CipherHandler();
    private final Validator validator = new Validator();

    @GetMapping(value = "/captcha/demo/text", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Captcha> getTextCaptcha() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String solution = gen.generate(4);
        Captcha captcha = handler.toCaptcha(solution, ch, "SomeSaltSource", "myPassword", renderer, 200, 600, true);
        System.out.println("Serving TextCaptcha took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds.");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(captcha);
    }
```

The encrypting method:

```
public byte[] encryptString(byte[] input, String password, Serializable saltSource, byte[] ivBytes) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The supplied password is empty or null. Encryption can not proceed.");
        }
        try {
            Cipher cipher = getCipher(password, saltSource, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ivBytes);
            byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(input);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
            outputStream.write( ivBytes );
            outputStream.write( cipherBytes );
            return outputStream.toByteArray( );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.fatal("Fatal error producing byte array data of the salt source object: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            log.fatal("Unknown algorithm specified for token encryption: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            log.fatal("Unknown padding specified for token encryption: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            log.fatal("Fatal error during token encryption: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I decided to log the time before and after calling the method.

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
byte[] encryptedToken = cipherHandler.encryptString(captchaText.getBytes(), password, saltSource);
System.out.println("Generating token took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds.");
```

When using spring boot I get the following:

```
Generating token took 88 milliseconds.
Generating token took 92 milliseconds.
Generating token took 90 milliseconds.
Generating token took 90 milliseconds.
```

On wildfly however, I get:

```
18:25:37,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Generating token took 15 milliseconds.
18:25:39,449 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Generating token took 14 milliseconds.
18:25:42,776 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Generating token took 14 milliseconds.
18:25:44,206 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Generating token took 14 milliseconds.
```

Since it's possible I need to encrypt twice (because of how I want the token to look) this essentially ruins the response time for the service.

Can someone explain to my where this difference comes from and what I could do to improve performance when running the application with spring boot?

I made sure both times are running on the same JDK (17) and swapped the embedded tomcat in spring for netty but saw no difference. Both are running on my machine locally.

I expected the response time on spring to be around the same as the with the application running on wildfly.

Comment: Try using a profiler - it will show where exactly CPU time is spent in both cases.

Comment: I have tried with the profiler but couldn't get to the bottom of it. However I noticed building the .jar and running it over the command line the Spring version is now on par with the Wildfly one but running it from within IntelliJ is still slow. Is it possible that running it through intelliJ makes it slower? Do they share resources when run that way or something?